# Laravel sendmail driver not works. Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

Laravel `sendmail` driver does not work.

It gives me this error:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.
>   (full error list you can see here https://pastecode.xyz/view/f28c82a3).

If I use log `driver` then it does work.

```
class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function send()
    {
        $objDemo           = new \stdClass();
        $objDemo->demo_one = 'Demo One Value';
        $objDemo->demo_two = 'Demo Two Value';
        $objDemo->sender   = 'SenderUserName';
        $objDemo->receiver = 'ReceiverUserName';

        Mail::to("receiver@example.com")->send(new DemoEmail($objDemo));
    }
}
```

**class DemoEmail**

```
class DemoEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The demo object instance.
     *
     * @var Demo
     */
    public $demo;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($demo)
    {
        $this->demo = $demo;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('sender@example.com')
                    ->view('mails.demo')
                    ->with([
                        'testVarOne' => '1',
                        'testVarTwo' => '2',
                    ]);
    }
}
```

**Blade text**

```
Hello <i>{{ $demo->receiver }}</i>,
<p>This is a demo email for testing purposes! Also, it's the HTML version.</p>

<p><u>Demo object values:</u></p>

<div>
    <p><b>Demo One:</b>&nbsp;{{ $demo->demo_one }}</p>
    <p><b>Demo Two:</b>&nbsp;{{ $demo->demo_two }}</p>
</div>

<p><u>Values passed by With method:</u></p>

<div>
    <p><b>testVarOne:</b>&nbsp;{{ $testVarOne }}</p>
    <p><b>testVarTwo:</b>&nbsp;{{ $testVarTwo }}</p>
</div>

Thank You,
<br/>
<i>{{ $demo->sender }}</i>
```

All files are in UTF-8 encoding, how to fix this?
Default php function mail() works well

Laravel 5.6